# Upgrading Distro from Luna to Freya

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, updates, release-loki

I used the following commands to try and upgrade to Freya.
"sudo apt-get update" - no problem
"sudo apt-get upgrade" - no problem
"sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" - what? nothing available ?
From such a class act as Elementary, I expected better.
I even went as far as going into the GUI and using software updater. I found the same result, no upgrade available.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't currently a way to upgrade from one release of elementary OS to another. From the [release announcement](http://blog.elementary.io/post/116134677986/freya-is-here):

> elementary OS Luna users should back up their data and perform a clean install.

Upgrading to elementary OS Loki will probably [require a clean install as well](https://twitter.com/elementary/status/730802325967642624). Upgrade support is [planned](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1486694) for a future version of elementary OS, though.

Comment: what about this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/16483/170

Answer (score 2):

What makes the switch from luna -> freya or now freya -> loki a little bit more comfortable is to use Aptik Migration Utility

EDIT : It seems it now exists only in a paid version.