# Direct update from Freya to Loki?

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, updates, release-loki

The last time, when elementary Freya was released, we had to do a clean install from Luna.

Will there be any option to directly upgrade to loki from Freya once Loki stable is released?

I have spent days to setup my system and it would be hard to set it up again.

Comment: The solution from Fishdrowned is a useful one. Point 9 of it calls for clarification though by the author: how to uncomment the specified files and where to replace trusty with xenial.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/elementary/status/730802325967642624) from the official elementary OS Twitter account, it won't be possible to directly upgrade. A clean install will be required.

See also: [Should I download loki beta or freya?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6733/should-i-download-loki-beta-or-freya/)

Answer (score 5):

This [has already been answered](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/5617/upgrading-distro-from-luna-to-freya/5618#5618) however maybe some keywords need to be added to the original question so it can be found more easily.

Please let us know which search terms you tried.

Comment: upgrade from Luna to Freya might very well be a different issue than upgrading from Freya to Loki. So, this has not been already answered.

Comment: If you dig into the post I linked to, you'll find a tweet linked from May 12 explicitly stating that upgrading from Freya to Loki will not be supported this time around. https://twitter.com/elementary/status/730802325967642624

Answer (score 1):

The official answer is: No

**But** I did manage to upgrade from freya to loki directly today.

First, upgrade Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04, and then upgrade the elementary OS stuff.

Here's how (may not working for everyone, because I got many exceptions, and have done a lot of manual intervention):

1. `apt update`, `apt upgrade`, `apt dist-upgrade`;
2. Make sure `Prompt=lts` in file`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`;
3. Edit `/etc/lsb-release`, change `DISTRIB_CODENAME=freya` to `DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty`
4. `do-release-upgrade` (I got `No new release found` at the beginning, then I tried `update-manager -c`). Your 3rd party apt sources will be disabled automatically, and the term `trusty` will be updated to `xenial` in file `/etc/apt/source.list`;
5. Downloading Ubuntu xenial upgrades;
6. I was unable to finish installing upgrades because of error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment` in file `/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-e78072qe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py`
7. So I did `apt update`, `apt upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade` to finish (maybe I guess) the installation;
8. Don't reboot your computer right now, the previous elementary components have been removed by `apt upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade`;
9. Re-enable the 3rd party apt sources by uncommenting *.list files in directory `/etc/apt/source.list.d/`, and replace `trusty` with `xenial`;
10. `apt update`
11. `apt install pantheon-greeter pantheon-shell pantheon-terminal pantheon-files slingshot-launcher slingshot gala`
12. `apt install switchboard wingpanel switchboard-plug-applications switchboard-plug-bluetooth switchboard-plug-display switchboard-plug-datetime switchboard-plug-keyboard switchboard-plug-locale switchboard-plug-mouse-touchpad switchboard-plug-networking switchboard-plug-notifications switchboard-plug-online-accounts switchboard-plug-pantheon-shell switchboard-plug-parental-controls switchboard-plug-power switchboard-plug-printers switchboard-plug-security-privacy switchboard-plug-sharing switchboard-plug-useraccounts switchboard-plug-users`
13. I got conflict errors so I removed python3-aptdaemon: `apt remove python3-aptdaemon` and then continued `apt upgrade`;
14. `apt autoremove`
15. `reboot` and loki is up

I may have forgotten something because I didn't do records in the upgrade process, the above steps are rearranged from the bash history.