# System broken due to faulty upgrade

Tags: system-installation, system

I had elementary OS Freya installed on my computer. Knowing that there's no official way to upgrade to Loki from Freya I decided upgrade it manually [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/direct-update-from-freya-to-loki) answer. I don't blame the answer posted in that thread. I may have done something wrong. I got ended with a broken system. When I power on I just see Dell logo, after that screen turns black.

Comment: I am afraid a clean install will be needed. Anyways, I have voted up this one for you. Let's see what others say.

Comment: Well, no one is talking i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please perform a clean install. elementary OS has don't support rolling release like Ubuntu.

Comment: What about the my files?

Comment: Here's what you can do, when you insert elementary bootable media enter `Try elementary` and backup your files to a external drive or something like that.